# How to upload a .csv file into MySql table with condition in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload .csv file into my mysql database table. my coding is working properly. what i need is i want to upload records based on some condition. If the condition is true then only the data upload into Database. Here is My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload CSV and Insert into Database Using PHP</title>
<head>
<body>
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Upload CSV: <input type='file' name='csv_data' /> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='import' />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

       if (!empty($_FILES['csv_data']['name'])) {
            if(pathinfo( $_FILES['csv_data']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) =='csv') {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_data']['tmp_name'], "r");

 $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[0]);
                    $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[1]);

                    $check="select id from m_tl_course";
                    $che=get_records_sql($check);
                    foreach ($che as $ch){
                        $re=$ch->id;
                    }

  if($re == $item2){

                    $import = "INSERT into tbl_csv values('','$item1','$item2')";
                    mysqli_query($dbConnection, $import);
                    echo "<script>alert('Master Course Files Uploaded Successfully')</script>";
                }else
                {
                echo "<script>alert('Id Not Match')</script>";
                }
                fclose($handle);
                print "Import done";
            }
            else{
               echo "only csv file allowed"; 
            }
        } else {
            echo "Please select file";
        }
    }
```

Here  i retrive an id from m_tl_course table and store it into a variable $re, and  check if the variable $re is equal to my .csv field item2 means then only records upload into my table.

This coding is working fine.But if i upload 3 records from .csv means only last record will be stored into my table.

How to solve this error. Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

In these instances I tend to use a temporary table to import the full csv file. The benefits of this are

1. you can allow mySQL validation routines to validate the data and
2. it allows you to use a SQL command to move appropriate data into your tbl_csv recordset.

The section below should be moved out of the loop to the top as you continuously read the same data for each line you read in from the csv

```
                $check="select id from m_tl_course";
                $che=get_records_sql($check);
                foreach ($che as $ch){
                    $re=$ch->id;
                }
```

You should also consider an associative array keyed on ID and use is set thus...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload CSV and Insert into Database Using PHP</title>
<head>
<body>
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Upload CSV: <input type='file' name='csv_data' /> <input type='submit'    name='submit' value='import' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   if (!empty($_FILES['csv_data']['name'])) {
        if(pathinfo( $_FILES['csv_data']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) =='csv') {

            // Get Current ID list and place it into an associative array
            $check="select id from m_tl_course";
            $che=get_records_sql($check);
            foreach ($che as $ch){
                $arrId[ $ch->id] = true; // just want to set an array
            }
 $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_data']['tmp_name'], "r");
 $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[0]);
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[1]);


  if(isset($arrId[$item2])){

                $import = "INSERT into tbl_csv values('','$item1','$item2')";
                mysqli_query($dbConnection, $import);
                echo "<script>alert('Master Course Files Uploaded Successfully')</script>";
            }else
            {
            echo "<script>alert('Id Not Match')</script>";
            }
            fclose($handle);
            print "Import done";
        }
        else{
           echo "only csv file allowed"; 
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select file";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did not set your brackets properly. See my comment in the below code, to see which bracket I added:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
       if (!empty($_FILES['csv_data']['name'])) 
       {
            if(pathinfo( $_FILES['csv_data']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION) =='csv') 
            {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_data']['tmp_name'], "r");

                $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                {
                    $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[0]);
                    $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $data[1]);

                    $check="select id from m_tl_course";
                    $che=get_records_sql($check);

                    foreach ($che as $ch)
                    {
                        $re=$ch->id;
                    }

                    if($re == $item2)
                    {
                        $import = "INSERT into tbl_csv values('','$item1','$item2')";
                        mysqli_query($dbConnection, $import);
                        echo "<script>alert('Master Course Files Uploaded Successfully')</script>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<script>alert('Id Not Match')</script>";
                    }

                    fclose($handle);
                    print "Import done";
                }//INSERTED THIS BRACKET
            }
            else
            {
                echo "only csv file allowed"; 
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Please select file";
        }
}

?>
```